# Safari push notifications using Node.js

Tags: safari-push-notifications

I have some queries below

1. How to integrate safari push notification using `node.js` after creating certificates of website.
2. How to get authentication token.
3. Device token

Please tell me the actual flow,I followed this link https://github.com/connorlacombe/Safari-Push-Notifications but, I get some version Issues.

Comment: plus1 for this, did you find anything out?